# Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state requires payable

Tags: solidity, error, compiler

I'm trying to change the an address data variable to a one, which is selected via a function.

Keep getting the below error.

Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.

```
address public winneraddress;

function getHighestBidID() public onlyOwner view returns (uint highestID, address _highestidaddress) {
    require(bids.length > 0,"Bid length");
    uint highestAmount = 0;
    for (uint i=0; i<bids.length; i++) {
        if (bids[i].amount > highestAmount) {
            highestAmount = bids[i].amount;
            highestID = i;
            _highestidaddress = bids[highestID].bidderAddress;
        }
    }
    winneraddress = _highestidaddress;
}
        mapping(address => uint256) public payments; //List of payments done to the Contract

    function makeBid(string memory _extraData) public inState(State.Active) payable returns(uint bidIterator) {
    require(msg.value > 0, "No value inserted");
    require(bidders <= 3, "Contract reached max registrations");
    require(payments[msg.sender] == 0, 'Sender previously paid into escrow.');
    bids.push(Bid(msg.sender, msg.value, _extraData, true));
    payments[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    bidders ++; 
    return bids.length - 1;
} 
    /*function withdraw() external inState(State.WinnerSelected) payable{
    require(msg.sender != winneraddress && winneraddress != address(0));
    payments[msg.sender].transfer(bids[msg.value].amount);
}*/
```

Any ideas how to fix it and what is causing the error?

Comment: Either get rid of the `view`, or get rid of the assignment `winneraddress = _highestidaddress;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let's go over the compilation error that you're getting:**

---

> Function declared as view

That one is clearly true, since this is how you've declared the function:

```
function getHighestBidID() public onlyOwner view ...
```

---

> But this expression modifies the state

That one is also true, since you are indeed modifying one of the state-variables:

```
winneraddress = _highestidaddress;
```

---

A `view` function can read state-variables, but it cannot write (modify) them.

So either get rid of the `view`, or get rid of the `winneraddress = _highestidaddress`.

Comment: I'd like to set a require statement that winneraddress is not required. 
require (!= winneraddress), any ideas what is the exact syntax?

Thanks again.

Comment: @user51821: If you explain to what what you mean by "winneraddress is not required", then I might be able to answer that.

Comment: I'm trying to write a function where users can withdraw the funds they deposited in the contract. However, the winner whose address we've set above using highest address wont be able to withdraw since this amount will only be withdrawn by the contract owner.  Thus a function for all the bidders except the one selected winner by the contract owner.

Comment: So function `withdraw` should start with `require(msg.sender != winneraddress)` but you should probably also ensure that function `getHighestBidID` has already been invoked in order to determine the winner, so perhaps your statement in function `withdraw` should actually be  `require(msg.sender != winneraddress && winneraddress != address(0))`.

Comment: Wow perfect, many thanks. You're a life saver.

Comment: I think you have a dangerous stateful logic here, where you need to know the order of function calls, between the `getHighestBidID` function and the `withdraw` function. Also, when should the `getHighestBidID` function be called, how many times can it be called, who can call it? You should consider all these questions very carefully.

Comment: Just to double confirm "owner.transfer((address(this).balance))" would transfer the amount to the bidders correct? And may I ask what does address(0) mean?

Comment: What is `owner` and who is "the bidders"??? `address(0)` means an `address` type variable whose value is `0`. Technically, it is a cast of `uint` to `address`.

Comment: By owner I mean contract owner, and bidders I mean not the winning address. Other addresses whom didnt get selected to be the winner

Comment: Assuming that `owner` is an `address` variable, `owner.transfer((address(this).balance))` would transfer the entire balance of the contract (amount of ether owned by the contract) to `owner`, whoever that is (I can't tell because I don't see the rest of your code, but I'm taking a wild guess that it is the account with which you deploy the contract (assuming you have `owner = msg.sender` in the contract's constructor)).

Comment: Yes that is correct. However, dont know how to transfer the value with which the users whom bid in the contract with certain values back to them their msg.value I mean. That would be a function called by those bidders.

Any ideas?

Comment: msg.sender.transfer(msg.value)?

Comment: `msg.sender.transfer(msg.value)` won't help you, as you'll just be transferring to the caller what the caller has just transferred to the contract within the function-call.

Comment: `bidder.transfer(value)` would do what you want I suppose, though you'll have to figure out what `bidder` is and what `value` is.

Comment: I already have an array of bids where I store the address of each bidder, as well as their deposits, tried something like the below. However, keeps failing not sure how to do it with correct syntax. 
bids.bidderAddress.transfer(bids.amount);

Comment: @user51821: Do you have sufficient funds in your contract in order to pay those amounts to those bidders?

Comment: May I ask why do I need funds, wont the bidders big by depositing to the contract their msg.value and when they withdraw they claim it? However, can add funds yes but dont understand why

Comment: I've added my make bid function and withdraw function in the question, thinking of using the payments mapping to send the data to the bidders. However, not sure if  payments[msg.sender].transfer(msg.value) would work or not.

Issue now is I cant get the value bidder deposited, not sure to use msg.value since the caller's value is the msg.value and dont know syntax to get         bids[msg.value].amount from array.

Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies for the many comments I've tried this function, can you confirm if does the job.

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner returns (uint test) {
        require(msg.sender != winneraddress && winneraddress != address(0));
        for (uint i=0; i<bids.length; i++) {
            if (msg.sender == bids[i].bidderAddress){
                bids[i].amount = test;
                msg.sender.transfer(test);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95645/discussion-on-answer-by-goodvibration-function-declared-as-view-but-this-expres).